# Looking for API that lets me communicate between two of my applications

Tags: windows, gratis, api, web-server

Im new to APIs in general, so please excuse any questions you may deem trivial - I probably don't :)

**Question:**
I have two apps, each one on a different machine (lets call them main and second) and an SQL Database(DB), which is hosted on main.
I want my main app to be able to GET/PUSH data from the DB and my second app to do the same - all in a json format if possible...

Now, I could go about writing my own API but I fear I have not have enough practice in C# to achieve this. This is why I was hoping there might be an API in existence already for this particular case.
I have a webserver with DB (Apache, XAMMP) installed, if this is of interested.

I have attached a picture of the general workflow, or at least how I'm imagening it to be.
[image: General workflow]

Like I said, Im new. I might be asking the wrong questions here or giving the wrong info. Just let me know if any other questions arise!
Any tips or help of any kind is warmly appreciated!
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Hello, your question doesn't quite make sense indeed. The arrows pointing from API to database especially. Databases can't really interact with APIs by themselves. I'd recommend learning the basics of web app design first before asking. Plus, as you're learning, I'd recommend to learn modern technologies like Docker instead of outdated XAMPP local server.

Comment: As far as I am concerned they do.. In a way, they GET and PUSH data, no? I believe this isnt the right space for this question. But dont worry thanks for trying :)

Comment: No, they don't "push" any data. Data is requested from them and they only answer.